Что за метка [users]?
Недавно наткнулся на метку users (63 вопроса, описания нет). И не понял когда её надо использовать.
Обычно её используют в впросе где как-то фигурируют пользователи. И в база-данных, и в wpf -- то есть не очень понятно что конкретно имеется ввиду.
Что это за метка? Не meta-метка ли это?
